# Canon MG3600 Series (WiFi) says print job completed but won't print (22.04)

Tags: networking, 22.04, printing, canon

When I started using Ubuntu 22.04 about a year ago, my printer was added automatically over WiFi and worked without any issues (with the exception of some applications). A couple of weeks ago, I started having issues with the printer showing up twice, and one selection worked, and the other didn't, so I deleted the one that wouldn't work. Since then, I cannot print at all over WiFi, although I have now found that printing over USB works fine.
Initially, on the print setup screen, it would say "Rejecting Jobs." I tried removing and adding the printer again, and checking "Enabled" and "Accepting Jobs" in Printer Properties. I checked the drivers and it is using the raw driver which is supposed to be compatible with this printer (and I think it is because it worked before.)
This is when it started saying that the print job was completed but nothing actually printed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.

You could get more information by watching `sudo journalctl  --follow` aa you try to print.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Here's what I've tried so far:
I booted a clean USB install of Ubuntu to check the default settings of the printer and verify the printer worked. 
Using the CUPS GUI, I tried to modify the settings to match (the driver and connection was different) but when I tried to change the driver to the correct one, I got the error "cups-driverd failed to get PPD file- see error_log for details." Checked logs, but didn't see anything having to do with cups. Can you think of what to do from here?

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.